# Heroku: TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, heroku, foreman

Noobie to Heroku/Django here, this is my Procfile:

```
web: python testapp/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

For some reason I can't seem to load my templates when i try to load it in my browser. Works normally under `python manage.py runserver`, anyone know what the problem is here? Is it a case of being unable to load my static files?

The precise error message is:foreman start

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /test/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/
```

Comment: is the django app you wrote added to the list of INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py? and is the app template located in ..../app_name/templates/app_name/index.html folder?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using the PROJECT_ROOT directory defined earlier in my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../templates'),
)
```

It looks like Heroku simply needs a full path.